# How to link to create action using link_to tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to link to create action, and thought something like

```
    <%= link_to "Create new user", {controller: 'users' , action: 'create'}, method: 'post'  %>
```

, but when I click the generated link nothing happens and the url changes to

```
    http://0.0.0.0:3000/users?method=POST+%2Fusers
```

which indicates that the request is handled as a GET request and not a POST, any ideas ?

here is the create action from the users controller

```
        def create


        @user = User.new params[:user]

        if @user.save
            flash[:notice] = 'User has successfully been created.'
            redirect_to users_path
        else
            flash[:notice] = 'There was an error creating this user.'
            redirect_to :back
        end

end
```

Comment: can you post the result of `rake routes`

Comment: users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy

Answer (score 0):

In rails: `<%= link_to 'Create new user' , new_user_path %>` , Check the [Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more info about routing.

Answer (score -1):

Try it with (not tested):

```
<%= link_to "Create new user", {controller: 'users' , action: 'create', method: 'post'}  %>
```

Comment: the url changes to http://0.0.0.0:3000/users?method=post but still nothing happens

Answer (score -1):

You should use the named paths as they are generated from your routes.

```
<%= link_to "Create new user", users_path, method: "post" %>
```

You can find the names of these methods by running `rake routes` and looking at the first column. Append `_path` for local links and `_url` for full URLs.

[More on named routes here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers)

Comment: still the same issue the create.html.erb page isn't loaded which means the request is handled as a GET one so the index.html.erb is loaded instead

Comment: In that case, you're missing the rails jquery helpers to convert the link. Make sure you have `jquery_ujs` required in `application.js`.

Comment: //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree . this is the application.js file.

Comment: Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-09-12 02:59:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true this warn is generated in the console everytime I click the link.

Comment: fixed! added this to the users controller                                    def new
  @user = User.new
  render 'create', method: 'post'
 end                                                                    and changed the path in the link_to tag to new_user_path